# Kotlin: workaround for no lateinit when using custom setter?

Tags: android, kotlin

In my activity I have a field that should be non-nullable and has a custom setter. I want to initialize the field in my `onCreate` method so I added `lateinit` to my variable declaration. But, apparently you cannot do that (at the moment): https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/lateinit-modifier-is-not-allowed-on-custom-setter/1999.

These are the workarounds I can see:

- Do it the Java way. Make the field nullable and initialize it with null. I don't want to do that.
- Initialize the field with a "default instance" of the type. That's what I currently do. But that would be too expensive for some types.

Can someone recommend a better way (that does not involve removing the custom setter)?

Comment: is the `onCreate` a part of a builder?

Comment: No, it's an overriden method inherited from class `Activity` that is invoked by Android as part of the app's lifecycle.

Comment: Why do you need a setter at all? It sounds like you could improve your architecture here.

Comment: My setter updates two UI widgets. I guess I could do it somehow without  setter. But it's a situation that I've faced mutliple times before. So I hoped there was a simple solution. Also I find properties are one of the coolest features that I missed in Java.

Comment: Could you add an example? How does the getter work? Do you store the value in a backing field? It sounds like a special use-case of yours.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access the code over the weekend. But essentially it does this: I have a dialog in which the user picks a date and time. The values are saved in the `Calendar` field in my activity. When setting the field a `TextView` (just shows date/time) and a `RecyclerView` (lists entries after date/time) are updated accordingly. And my problem is that I want to initialize the field with the current date/time when the activity is created. Oh, and I have no custom getter for the field.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Replace it with a property backed by nullable property:

```
private var _tmp: String? = null
var tmp: String
    get() = _tmp!!
    set(value) {_tmp=value; println("tmp set to $value")}
```

Or this way, if you want it to be consistent with `lateinit` semantics:

```
private var _tmp: String? = null
var tmp: String
    get() = _tmp ?: throw UninitializedPropertyAccessException("\"tmp\" was queried before being initialized")
    set(value) {_tmp=value; println("tmp set to $value")}
```

Comment: But I still get an error because I have to initialize my property

Comment: So, you want to use uninitialized property in Kotlin, but don't want it to be null or throw exception?

Comment: I tried to apply your upper solution. But I get an error because `tmp` is not initialized.

Comment: And you initialized it?

Comment: Ok, got my mistake. Instead of `_tmp=value` I tried `field=value`. Works now!

Comment: @Pavlus Agreed, this is a poor example, but it demonstrates how to combine a getter with a non-nullable property. Say for instance that your getter initializes the field when it's null, but you don't want to litter your code with elvis operators.

Comment: there's no need to back it with a nullable property. `_tmp` can be `lateinit`

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved by using a [backing property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties) (as per Pavlus's answer); however, I prefer to wrap it inside a [delegate](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) to avoid exposing it outside of the property's context:

```
open class LateInit<T: Any> : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> {
    protected lateinit var field: T

    final override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) = get()
    final override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) = set(value)

    open fun get() = field
    open fun set(value: T) { field = value }
}
```

This provides standard getters and setters that can be overridden with a custom implementation:

```
var upperCaseString by object : LateInit<String>() {
    override fun set(value: String) {
        field = value.toUpperCase()
    }
}
```

However, since this implementation requires extending the delegate, the generic type cannot be inferred from the property type. This can overcome by taking the custom getter and setter as parameters:

```
class LateInit<T: Any>(private val getter: FieldHolder<T>.() -> T = { field },
                       private val setter: FieldHolder<T>.(T) -> Unit = { field = it }) :
        ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> {
    private val fieldHolder = FieldHolder<T>()

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) = fieldHolder.getter()
    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) =
            fieldHolder.setter(value)

    class FieldHolder<T: Any> {
        lateinit var field: T
    }
}
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
private var upperCaseString: String by LateInit(setter = { field = it.toUpperCase() })
```

Comment: How to use isInitialized?

Comment: @the_prole: The delegating class could expose an `isInitialized` property if desired. However, in order to access it, you'll need to store a reference to it, instead of merely using it as a disposable property getter/setter delegate. At which point, it would probably be simpler to just use a backing property as per Pavlus' answer.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that you can also make your private property `lateinit` instead of making it nullable:

```
var tmp: T
    get() = _tmp
    set(value) {
        _tmp = value
        println("tmp set to $value")
    }

private lateinit var _tmp: T
```