# Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match

Tags: kotlin

I tried to check, lateinit variable is initialized or not in a function using reference operator. The function name and variable name is same in this case. So that Kotlin throws

> Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match

exception. Actually what's wrong in this code?

```
class ABC

class MyClass {
    private lateinit var abc: ABC

    fun abc() {
        if(!::abc.isInitialized){
            println("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a simple name clash. The compiler does not know whether you're referring to the method `abc` or the property `abc`. A renaming fixes the problem:

```
class MyClass {
    private lateinit var abc: ABC

    fun abcFun() {
        val prop = this::abc
        if (!::abc.isInitialized) {
            println("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: or calling the property : `_abc`

Comment: It’s probably relevant to know what purpose the function is supposed to have anyway.

Comment: @crgarridos what do you mean "or"? You still did the renaming only not in the function that is it.

Comment: I mean exactly what you said. in my opinion, was better to pollute private members than public API. but matter of personal taste

Answer (score 5):

You can disambiguate the reference by extracting a variable and explicitly specifying its type:

```
class ABC

class MyClass {
    private lateinit var abc: ABC

    fun abc() {

        val abc: KProperty0<ABC> = ::abc
        if(!abc.isInitialized){
            println("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there's a limitation that `isInitialized` can only be called on a literal callable reference, i.e. only on literal `::abc` value and not on that value extracted to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have a property called `abc`, which can be accessed by calling the Kotlin property accessor `this.abc` (sort of "getter") and you define another method with the same name, so it doesn't recognize which one to reference with syntax `::abc`.

This is also stated by the error message from the IDE:

> Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match:
>
> - private final lateinit var abc: ABC defined in MyClass
> - public final fun abc(): Unit defined in MyClass

Comment: is there any other way to overcome this issue

Comment: I would say that you need to rename your method/property. Why do you want them to have the same name? Just to have a custom getter? If that's the case, you can create a custom backing property, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46366869/kotlin-workaround-for-no-lateinit-when-using-custom-setter)

Comment: I don't think it's related to the getter, which will also be `getAbc()`

Comment: Since the property is defined as `private`, there will be no `getAbc()` in the bytecode. So by "getter" I meant the Kotlin way of getting a property value (in this case, `this.abc`). I'll update my answer to make it more clear

Comment: I see, that’s true :)

Answer (score 1):

If you would access the function `abc` or the property `abc` on an instance of MyClass without the reference syntax, it would actually work, although I would not recommend it. See here:

```
class ABC

class MyClass{
    private lateinit var abc: ABC

    fun abc(){
        abc
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val c = MyClass()
  c.abc()
}
```

This code compiles without any problems.

But this is not what you want. Create a backing field `_abc` and access it via a property without backing field `abc`. This way you can return a default instance of `ABC`, if `_abc` has not been initialized.

```
class MyClass {

    private lateinit var _abc: ABC

    val abc: ABC get() {
        if(!::_abc.isInitialized){
            println("Uninitialized")
            return ABC() // some default instance
        }
        println("Initialized")
        return _abc
    }

    fun initABC() {
        _abc = ABC()
    }
} 

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val c = MyClass()
  c.abc
  c.initABC()
  c.abc
}
```

Output:

> Uninitialized
>   Initialized