# Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match. In Picasso (into) function

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, picasso

I got stuck upon one of the Picasso so-called open fun methods.

I am using URL in my recyclerview to get images. I don't think it is the problem with recyclerview. I think its more likely a bug.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
      Picasso.get().load(arrayPlaces[position].url).into(holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainImage))
    }
```

[image]

For Solution I tried:

[This](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2717)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804704/overload-resolution-ambiguity-all-these-functions-match)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779666/how-to-fix-overload-resolution-ambiguity-in-kotlin-no-lambda)

GitHub :
https://github.com/sophin123/RecyclerViewwithImages

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding ImageView in findViewById<>()

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
      Picasso.get().load(arrayPlaces[position].url).into(holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.mainImage))
    }
```